# python django invoicing program, link with a foreign key and save both models

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, foreign-keys

I'm newer on python. I'm trying to create a simple invoice app with invoice header and invoice lines for details as following. How i can create view to create and save new invoice and new invoices details linked between them with foreign  ? And to show it on a template ?

Models :

```
class invoice(models.Model):
    invoice_number = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    client = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class invoiceline(models.Model):
    invoice_number = models.ForeignKey(invoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    article = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Views:

```
def invoice_create(request):
    print(request.POST)
    invoice_number = request.GET['invoice_number']
    date = request.GET['date']
    client = request.GET['client']
    invoice_details = invoice(invoice_number=invoice_number, date=date, client=client)
    invoice_details.save()
    return redirect('/')

def invoiceline_create(request):
    print(request.POST)
    invoice_number = request.GET['invoice_number']
    article = request.GET['article']
    quantity = request.GET['quantity']
    price = request.GET['price']
    invoicelines_details = invoiceline(invoice_number=invoice_number, article=article, quantity=quantity, price=price)
    invoicelines_details.save()
    return redirect('/invoiceline_index')
```

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

first you should get an invoice from an invoice table by invoice_number and after you set this on invoice_number of invoiceline table. look like:

```
def invoiceline_create(request):
    print(request.POST)
    invoice_number = request.GET['invoice_number']
    article = request.GET['article']
    quantity = request.GET['quantity']
    price = request.GET['price']
    try:
        find_invoice = invoice.objects.get(invoice_number=invoice_number)
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
    invoicelines_details = invoiceline(invoice_number=find_invoice, article=article, quantity=quantity, price=price)
    invoicelines_details.save()
    return redirect('/invoiceline_index')
```

Comment: good luck.
please accepted this answer. thanks. @youssefmohamed